# How can I update the listview content each time on a button click?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I need to update my `ListView` content (which is retrieved from a database) each time when a button is clicked. I am trying to include a book search functionality in my android application.

For that I am taking some keywords as input.On a button click the book details matching the key word is retrieved from database and is displayed in the list view in the same layout.

The code I have written will create a new `ListView` with updated content on each button click and display it below the previous `ListView`.Which I need to correct.

A preferred solution will be to update the list view content on a button click.
Removing the previously displayed  `ListView` is also acceptable.

For that I tried `getListView().inValidate()` but didn't work. `notifyDataSetChanged()` also is not working .Please help :)

```
           public class searchActivity extends ListActivity {  
    String keyword;
    Button bsearch;
    EditText input;  
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray books = null;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> booksList;
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);      
        bsearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
        input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        booksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        adapter=newSimpleAdapter(searchActivity.this,booksList,R.layout.search_list,new String[]{"bookname"},new int[] {R.id.bookname}); 

        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    bsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){ 
            keyword=input.getText().toString();
            new LoadAll().execute();
        }
    }); 
    }
    class LoadAll extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword", keyword));
            JSONObject json =   Jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.2.2  /libraryconnect/search_book.php", "GET", params);
            Log.d("All books: ", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1) {
                    books = json.getJSONArray("books");
                    for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = books.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = c.getString("bookname");
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("bookname",bookname);
                        booksList.add(map); 
                    }
                } else {
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }   
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: no need on invalidate(),notifyDataSetChanged() directly add the updated adapter to the list in on buttonclicklistener

Comment: I think I would do setAdapter on onCreate, not onPostExecute

Comment: @Duc tried that too.But no change!

Answer (score 1):

In your `onClick(View v)`, call [notifyDataSetChanged ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) from your `adapter`

Comment: Is it possible to use notifyDataSetChanged() with ListAdapter??

Comment: I think that is the problem, notifyDataSetChanged() works for ArrayAdapter. Because ListAdapter doesn't extend BaseAdapter so it doesn't work. You might need to build your own adapter if you really need ListAdapter, otherwise, try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102060/android-listview-refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can change data set of your list view and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it,instead of creating new list view or new adapter for it.

You can find what you need to know in [Android ListView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: I already tried notifyDataSetChanged() .It is not working and I am using ListAdapter

Comment: @Revathy where do you call notifyDataSetChanged()?And how you change data set?

Comment: I called it from my button's onclick() function.

Comment: K thanku for the reply.This tutorial is focusing on the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I edited my code and used notifyDataSetChanged() but still new list view is created at each button click.how can I correct it?

Comment: @Revathy remove `getListView().setAdapter(adapter);` from `onPostExecute()` method.